# Which one is a correct sentence 'classes has started' or 'classes have started'

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

When I asked why not the classes has started, one of my friend suggested a correction: "**have** started"

My question is: which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

"Classes" is a plural noun. The verb must also take a plural form to [agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics)) with the noun.

> One class has started.
>
> Two classes have started.

Answer (score 1):

The present simple of the verb **have** goes like this:

> *singular*
>   I have
>   you have
>   he/she/it **has**
>
> *plural*
>   we have
>   you have
>   they have

You will notice that the only case of **has** is third person singular- he/she/it **has**.

**classes** is plural, so the correct verb case is **have**.